# i can't get my plugin to use all tree grid columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

As you may see from my code I'm a newbie web designer.
I learned CSS grids and am trying to implement it in to my website. I am trying to make my navigation bar use the 2nd and 3rd grid columns and the dsm instagram plugin to use all three grid columns on the next row under. But instead for some reason the navbar is using the 2nd column and the plugin is using the 3rd column all on the same row.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2fr;
}

.logo {
  grid-columns: 1/2;
  width: 200px;
}

.main-nav {
  grid-columns: 2/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  padding-top: 20px;
}


/*gets rid of bullet points*/

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  all: unset;
  font-family: 'raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #a08b13;
}

.dsm-instagram-feed {
  grid-columns: 1/3;
  grid-rows: 2/3
}


}
.contact-box {
  border: 3px solid #a08b13;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
.contact-box:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="grid">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="hairbychaya.html"><img src="cmc_logo.jpg" class="logo"></img>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="main-nav">

      <li> <a href="hairbychaya.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li> <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
      <li> <a href="survices.html">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li> <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
      <li class="contact-box"> <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="dsm-instagram-feed" data-embed-id='3818'></div>
  <script src='https://www.displaysocialmedia.com/app/embed/instagram-feed/widget.js'></script>
```

Comment: I edited your post right now and just want to reply to your "p.s.". Did you already read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your code is buggy - I would not wonder if fixing the bugs would solve your issue. Try to post better formated. Do some very basic tuts on CSS and HTML. Anyway a good question!

Comment: @Axel can you explain what you mean by "your code is buggy" i can't really find bugs in the code that may be do to my inexperience can you help me identify what you would considera bug thank you

Comment: I left the bugs when I made the first edit to your post. I did so by intention because I thought that they may be part of the problem though also part of the solution. Now @kukkuz fixed all these bugs. Have a look at the revision history (you can do so by clicking the link above the last editor "edited xyz hours ago"). In addition i strongly recommend to have a look at https://html5boilerplate.com - compare the boilerplate with your markup. You made very basic mistakes. You can also use https://validator.w3.org to validate your markup - by doing so you have instant feedback about what's wrong.

Comment: @Axel i saw kukkuz code and all he did was changed the spacing which dident fix any of the issues when i ran that code and i also ran the code on validator.w3.org and fix all the errors and i am stil having these issues i dont mean to be a nudge but I'm just asking you to take a look at the code and tell me what you think is the issue it's just that this has been bothering me all day and it feels like i have tried everything and nothing seems to work i would be immensely greatfull if you can help me solve this issue thank you

Comment: Dear @prog if it would be "quick thing" to help you out I would do it for sure. But I'm not so much into that CSS-grid stuff (its on my list - but not right now because its [not widely supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid)). I'm quite sure to be able to mockup something that would achieve your desired behavior but it would be "kinda old school". If this would be ok for you then feel free to describe exactly your requirements and add a screenshot how everything should look... I webdevelop stuff that is above "caniuse > 95%" - you know

Comment: Check your CSS property names very carefully.

Comment: @WesLord which CSS property's are you refereeing to in specific

Answer (score 1):

You reference `grid-columns` and `grid-rows`, but those are not actual properties. Things appear to be working once you remove the pluralization of those four occurrences.

```
.logo {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  ...
}

.main-nav {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  ...
}

...

.dsm-instagram-feed {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2/3
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bqu8ton3/